# Create subdomain by cpanel api

Tags: php, subdomain, cpanel

I register on youhosting.com and use domain that registered on godaddy.com. I want to create new subdomain by programming. I have already see the tutorial on [cPanel Documentation 1](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/How+to+call+cPanel+API+1+and+API+2+Functions+With+WHM+AP) and [Doc 2](https://documentation.cpanel.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=360752#SubDomain::addsubdomain)

After I implement it, it show errors :

```html
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'curl_exec threw error "couldn't connect to host" for https://bodoamat.com:2087/xml-api/listips?' in /home/u937182156/public_html/xmlapi.php:748 Stack trace: #0 /home/u937182156/public_html/xmlapi.php(666): xmlapi->curl_query('https://bodoama...', '', 'Authorization: ...') #1 /home/u937182156/public_html/xmlapi.php(2055): xmlapi->xmlapi_query('listips') #2 /home/u937182156/public_html/listips_example.php(44): xmlapi->listips() #3 {main} thrown in /home/u937182156/public_html/xmlapi.php on line 748
```

```html
include 'xmlapi.php';

$ip='127.0.0.1';
$root_pass='mypassword';

 $xmlapi = new xmlapi($host);
 $xmlapi->set_port(2082);
 $xmlapi->password_auth($my_user, $my_pass);
 $xmlapi->set_debug(1);

print $xmlapi->api1_query($account, "Subdomain", "addsubdomain", array('user123', 'bodoamat.com'));
```

Any one may help me?

Thanks before

Comment: `"couldn't connect to host" for https://bodoamat.com:2087` is a pretty good indication of what is happening. The server at bodomat.com is not listening for connections on port 2087.

Comment: According to my experience with Hostmonster, If your hosting offers sub domains, so you will find the option of making new sub-domain directly in your cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xmlapi->api1_query($cpanelusr, 'SubDomain', 'addsubdomain', array('user123','bodoamat.com',0,0, '/public_html/directory_name'))
```